# CSS: bullet styles on lists

Tags: css

Why isn't the following working? I want the `ul` style to be mostly unbulleted (due to inherited code), but occasionally to be able to use it as a traditional bulleted list. So I've defined a special class for bulleted lists.

```
ul li {padding:0 0 0.5em 0; margin-left:0; list-style-type:none;}
ul.bulleted {padding:0 0 0 0; list-style-type: disc; color:red;}
```

The HTML:

```
<p>Intro text:</p>
        <ul class="bulleted">
            <li>blah</li>
            <li>blah</li>
            <li>blah</li>
        </ul>
```

This shows the list with red text, as expected: but without any bullets!

Baffled :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ul li` is more specific than `ul.bulleted` so it therefore takes precedence.

Try using `ul.bulleted li` for the second set of rules instead.

That will make it even *more* specific than the first rule, and allow it to be applied.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand :) It's so hard to debug CSS. Great concise & clear explanation, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your first style applies to the `li` items and removes their bullet, while the second applies to the `ul item ...

make your first rule ( *by removing the li* )

```
ul {padding:0 0 0.5em 0; margin-left:0; list-style-type:none;}
```

or your second

```
ul.bulleted li {padding:0 0 0 0; list-style-type: disc; color:red;}
```

depending on how other rules apply ..